# Big-Theta: Confusing time output for theta(n^3) algorithm

Tags: java, big-o

Im doing some time analysis on this random algorithm i've conjured. The results are confusing me...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int size = 1000; size <= 10000000; size *= 4){
            long start = System.nanoTime();
            algorithm(size);
            long end = System.nanoTime();
            System.out.println(size + " - " + (end-start)/1E6 + " ms");
        }
    }

    static void algorithm(int size){
        int count = 123456789;
        for (int a = 0; a < size; a++){
            for (int b = 0; b < size; b++){
                for (int c = 0; c < size; c++){
                    double blah = 0;
                    for (int k = 0; k < 1000; k++)
                        blah = Math.sqrt(count);
                }
            }
        }
    }

1000 - 711.623125 ms
4000 - 45053.60374 ms
16000 - 0.002234 ms
64000 - 0.001677 ms
256000 - 0.001676 ms
1024000 - 0.002794 ms
4096000 - 0.001676 ms
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 45 seconds)
```

Why does the total time dramatically drop at 16000? The first two values (1000 & 4000) make sense to me, but what causes the rest of them to take to little time even though they have to iterate through n^4 more?

Comment: Your method `algorithm` doesnt do anything of consequence. So the runtime decided to remove it

Comment: Why did it decide to remove it only at large input? Wouldn't the optimization occur for all input size?